# signalr .net client reconnect error

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, clients

I'm writing a program that makes remote desktop connection with signalr. I keep sending screenshots (in the .net client) for it. But when I reconnect to the server after a while, I get error: Connection started reconnecting before invocation result was received.

```
    public void ImageMain()
    {
       var querstring = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        querstring.Add("userid", "sessionlocal");
        var hubConnectionMouse = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8089/", querstring);
        Program p = new Program();

        IHubProxy myHubProxyMouse = hubConnectionMouse.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
        string a = "";
        try
        {
            hubConnectionMouse.Start().Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        byte[] ekran;

        while (true)
        {
            ekran = null;
            ekran = EkranGoruntusu();

            if (ekran.Length < 80000)
            {
                try
                {
                    myHubProxy.Invoke("addMessage", "sessionlocal", ekran).ContinueWith(task =>
                    {
                        if (task.IsFaulted)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("!!! image gönderilirken hata olıştu:{0} \n",
                                task.Exception.GetBaseException() + "tekrar bağlanılıyor....");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Add messgae" + "    gonderilecek ekran boyutu  " + ekran.Length);
                            Console.WriteLine("hub durumu" + hubConnection.State);

                        }
                    }).Wait();

                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("bağlantı hatas tekrar bağlanılıyor" + exception.Message);

                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("gonderilcek goruntü cok büyük");
            }


        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```